# jQuery count how many divs with a class there are and put into string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to count how many divs you have and put that number into a string

```
<div class="name">SOME TEXT</div>

<div class="name">SOME OTHER TEXT</div>

<div class="different">DIFFERENT TEXT</div>
```

So count the divs with class `name` and then put that into a string so the output would be this

```
var strNoDivs = 2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: BTW, `var strNoDivs = 2` is not a string, it's a number.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var nb = $('div.name').length;
```

Answer (score 4):

First option is:

```
var count= $('div.name').length;
```

or filter() function can be used too.

```
var count= $('div').filter('.aaa').length;
```

Answer (score 3):

`var strNoDivs = $('div.name').length;`

Done.

jQuery's [selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is based on the CSS selector syntax (which, I suppose, is only helpful information if you're already familiar with CSS selectors).

Answer (score 3):

```
var strNoDivs = $('div.name').length.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

`var noOfDivs = $('div.name').length`?

Using the [Length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property.

Comment: `<nit-pick>``.length` is a property, not a function. `</nit-pick>`

Answer (score 1):

Like this...

```
var divisions = $("div.name");
var strNoDivs = divisings.length.toString();
alert(strNoDivs);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference of [jQuery Forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-count-occurance-multiple-element-with-a-same-name) it can be done this way.

```
$('input[id*="name"]').length;
```